# Chrome profiler statistic grey area

Tags: google-chrome, backbone.js, profiling, google-chrome-devtools, memory-profiling

I am profiling my Backbone/Marionette application, but cannot figure this out. The memory used is 330mb, the image shows about 120mb used and about 60% percent grey area.

What does the grey area mean? Is this an effect of memory leaks?

[image: Chrome profiling statistics]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all other objects (not code, strings and arrays). You should be able to see them in the Summary view.